# Magento Enterprise Banners

Tags: magento

Magneto Enterprise has banners built-in. I want to get a particular banner in code and I am having trouble figuring out how to access a method inside of app/code/core/Enterprise/Banner/Model/Resource/Banner.php

I tried using this code:

```
Mage::getModel('banner/resource_resource')->getBannersContent(5,1);
```

but Magneto tells me it can't find the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been fighting this myself, and have been seriously hampered by the lack of documentation and discussion out there on manipulating Enterprise CMS banners in code. I'm now successfully pulling banner HTML into code, and based on your question this method should work for you as well.

First, `getModel('banner/resource_resource')` is going to return an `Enterprise_Banner_Model_Banner` object, but the `getBannersContent` method needs to be called from an `Enterprise_Banner_Model_Resource_Banner` object. To get the right object type, you need to call `getResource` on the first object:

```
Mage::getModel('enterprise_banner/banner')->getResource()
```

Now you can call `getBannersContent` like you did above, except that the first argument needs to be an array, not an int. So the following should work:

```
Mage::getModel('enterprise_banner/banner')
    ->getResource()
    ->getBannersContent(array(0 => 5), 1);
```